# SQL Query error from MS Access to VB Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

whats wrong with this query ?, i run it in my vb net app but i get "syntax error (missing operator) ", i copied from working sql query generated from access 2016 app.

query :

```
        Dim sqlquery As String = "Select tblCommissionsP.IDCommissionP, tblCategoryProducts.Nama, tblEmployees.Nama, tblCommissionsP.CommissionType, tblCommissionsP.CommissionRate
                            FROM tblCommissionsP INNER JOIN tblCategoryProducts On tblCommissionsP.IDCategoryProduct = tblCategoryProducts.IDCategoryProduct INNER JOIN tblEmployees On tblCommissionsP.IDEmployee = tblEmployees.IDEmployee"
```

error :

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'tblCommissionsP.IDCategoryProduct = tblCategoryProducts.IDCategoryProduct INNER JOIN tblEmployees On tblCommissionsP.IDEmployee = tblEmployees.IDEmploye'.'`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the code to:

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "Select tblCommissionsP.IDCommissionP, tblCategoryProducts.Nama, tblEmployees.Nama, tblCommissionsP.CommissionType, tblCommissionsP.CommissionRate" _
                       & " FROM tblCommissionsP INNER JOIN tblCategoryProducts On tblCommissionsP.IDCategoryProduct = tblCategoryProducts.IDCategoryProduct INNER JOIN tblEmployees On tblCommissionsP.IDEmployee = tblEmployees.IDEmployee"
```

Comment: don't work sir, i also tried to make it single line. same error

Answer (score 0):

it worked now,because more than one inner join, so i have to put parentheses

```
 (tblCommissionsP INNER JOIN tblCategoryProducts ON tblCommissionsP.IDCategoryProduct = tblCategoryProducts.IDCategoryProduct) INNER JOIN ...
```